# Qt 5.10.1 MinGW .. how to link a dll

Tags: qt5.5

I have a project that complies while linking to lib quazip.a. But the project crashes in the Qt IDE when trying to run it. In VS 2017 with Qt VS Tools I built the dll quazip.dll because the deployed project needs it. But the dll doesn't load with the error "Procedure entry point not found". Is there a way to link the dll in my project so an entry point can be found? Or is there a way to get the project to run in the IDE as well as deploy with the quazip.a lib? Or is there a way to build the quazip.dll in Qt MinGW?

Answer (score 0):

I got the quazip.dll from a Qt MinGW build of quazip. All is fine now.